# Can I bind multiple controls with single class?

Tags: wpf

I have one class named investmentdetails.
I created two different controls for displaying separate data (properties) from same class.
Is it possible?
If yes then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the DataContext of your parent control (Window, User Control, Grid etc.) to the InvestmentDetails class, then bind to individual properties.